# Automatically creating user profile

Tags: python, django, web-development-server

I am trying to create a system in which after my registration is completed a profile is automatically made and saved for the user. I have applied all my current knowledge but the following error keeps showing up.

IntegrityError at /register/
NOT NULL constraint failed: users_profile.standard

Request Method:POST

This is my views.py -

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from .form import UserRegisterForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(
                request, f'Your account has been created. You are now able to log in!')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})


@login_required
def profile(request):
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html')
```

and my signals.py -

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

EDIT - Here's my Profile Model -

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

Comment: can you add your Profile model code?

Comment: Please format your code as it will not work with the current formatting.

Comment: @TobiasBrösamle Done!

Comment: @NalinDobhal Done!

Comment: Are your signals actually being fired? Did you import the signals module anywhere so that they are registered?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I imported them in apps.py. If you want I can add the code.

Comment: Is there image field in UserRegisterForm. If not, profile won't be created. Or try null=True in image field in Profile model. and don't forget to migrate after making change.

Comment: @ClawHunter07 did you make any changes in your profile model? if yes then did you run makemigrations and migrate after that?

Comment: YES!! IT WORKED. I just remembered I had added an age field to the profile model but removed it later without migrating . Oh my god Thank you guys so much!! I appreciate it a lot y'all.